# How to skip null value in Chain of Responsibilities?

Tags: java

I understand the responsibility chain pattern. And I have such a question. As can be seen from my chain of responsibility, if the method does not return the locale to me, then it returns null. How can I go to the next item in the chain if it returns null?

```
public abstract class StandardLocaleHandler {

            protected StandardLocaleHandler localeHandler;


            public StandardLocaleHandler() {
                this.localeHandler = null;
            }

            protected abstract Locale getTrueLocale(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, List<String> localeList, String defaultLocale, Integer cookieAge);

            public void setNext(StandardLocaleHandler localeHandler) {
                this.localeHandler = localeHandler;
            }

            public StandardLocaleHandler getNext() {
                return localeHandler;
            }
        }

        public class GetLocaleByAvailable extends StandardLocaleHandler {

            @Override
            protected Locale getTrueLocale(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, List<String> localeList, String defaultLocale, Integer cookieAge) {
                if (isNull(req.getSession().getAttribute(LANG_ATTRIBUTE)) && isNull(req.getCookies())) {
                    return setAvailable(req, resp, localeList, defaultLocale, cookieAge);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

    public class GetLocaleBySession extends StandardLocaleHandler {

            @Override
            protected Locale getTrueLocale(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, List<String> localeList, String defaultLocale, Integer cookieAge) {
                if (nonNull(req.getSession().getAttribute(LANG_ATTRIBUTE))) {
                    LOG.debug(req.getParameter(LANG_ATTRIBUTE));
                    return new Locale((String) req.getSession().getAttribute(LANG_ATTRIBUTE));
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I formed my chain of repsonsibility on this way:

```
public class ChainBuilder {

    private List<StandardLocaleHandler> localeHandlers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addToFilterList(StandardLocaleHandler filter) {
        if (!localeHandlers.contains(filter)) {
            localeHandlers.add(filter);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Already in the list");
        }
    }

    public StandardLocaleHandler createChainOfResponsibility() {
        for (int i = 0; i < localeHandlers.size() - 1; i++) {
            localeHandlers.get(i).setNext(localeHandlers.get(i + 1));
        }
        return localeHandlers.get(0);
    }
}

ChainBuilder builder = new ChainBuilder();
        builder.addToFilterList(new GetLocaleByAvailable());
        builder.addToFilterList(new GetLocaleByParam());
        builder.addToFilterList(new GetLocaleBySession());
        builder.addToFilterList(new GetLocaleByCookie());

        StandardLocaleHandler handler = builder.createChainOfResponsibility();
        return handler.getTrueLocale(req, resp, localeList, defaultLocale, cookieAge);
```

How can I go to the next item in the chain if it returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change code to something like this

```
public class GetLocaleByAvailable extends StandardLocaleHandler {

        @Override
        protected Locale getTrueLocale(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp, List<String> localeList, String defaultLocale, Integer cookieAge) {
            Locale result = null;
            if (isNull(req.getSession().getAttribute(LANG_ATTRIBUTE)) && isNull(req.getCookies())) {
                result = setAvailable(req, resp, localeList, defaultLocale, cookieAge);
            }
            if (result == null) {
                StandardLocaleHandler nextHandler = getNext();
                if (nextHandler == null) {
                    return nextHandler.getTrueLocale(....);
                }
            }
            return result;              
        }
    }
```

And the same for another `Handler` class.

Answer (score 3):

```
public abstract class StandardLocaleHandler {
    public final Locale getTrueLocale() {
        Locale local = getTrueLocaleInternal();
        return local == null && localeHandler != null ? localeHandler.getTrueLocale() : local;
    }

    protected abstract Locale getTrueLocaleInternal();
}

public class GetLocaleByAvailable extends StandardLocaleHandler {

    @Override
    protected Locale getTrueLocaleInternal() {
        // TODO logic
        return null;
    }
}
```